# How to download file using Selenium and IE avoiding download prompt

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, download

I want to download file directly from web page without handling download prompt pop-up. I used for this purpose appropriate preferences for `Firefox`, something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
profile = FirefoxProfile ()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)   
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", folder_on_hard_drive) 
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", file_mime_type)
```

but I don't know how to apply these settings for `IE`. Please advice proper `desired capabilities` or other way how to do this best

Comment: why not just fetch the URL, then have python download said url? rather than clicking, and going through the manual process

Comment: @sircapsalot, the point is not actually to download the file, but to verify whether user can download it from page using `IE` or not. it's a test script

Comment: then it's plenty just to make sure the target url ends with the appropriate extension.