# Selenium find_element_by_xpath not working for SharePoint 2013

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to configure Selenium to open a SharePoint 2013 list and download it (export to excel). I can have selenium clicking in the List to show the option to Export to Excel, but when I use the xpath to click in Export to Excel I get an error sayng it doesnt find the xpath. Any idea why?

Html code of the button is:

```
<span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Export to<br>Excel</span>
```

Xpath is:

```
//*[@id="Ribbon.List.Actions.ExportToSpreadsheet-Medium"]/span[2]
```

Code and Print below.

Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

path_to_Ie = 'C:\\Python34\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe' # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path = path_to_Ie)
url = 'https://group.shareplace.test/sites/site2/Lists/Actions/AllItems.aspx'
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Ribbon.List-title']/a/span[1]").click()

time.sleep(4)


browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Ribbon.List.Actions.ExportToSpreadsheet-Medium']/span[2]").click()
```

[image]

Comment: What error? Provide `html` code for "Export to Excel" button

Comment: I updated the post. The error is that cant find the xpath. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code and let me know if it's not working properly:

```
xpath = '//span[@class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel"][contains(text(), "Export to")]'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked. Just a short question, it pop ups a IE alert asking if I want to Open or Save the file. Can selenium click on SAVE? I am trying to analyze the HTML but since it's a IE pop up i am not sure how to do it.. Thanks again.

Comment: I used browser.switch_to_alert() to select the dialog box but I am not able to press the save.

Comment: `selenium` could not handle clicking `Save` as this is a `OS` native pop-up, but not a web element. If you can use `FireFox` instead of `IE`, then try `FireFoxProfile` settings. I have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547712/how-to-download-file-using-selenium-and-ie-avoiding-download-prompt and it still got no answer...

Comment: I see, actually with browser.switch_to_alert()  seems that the dialog box is selected.. but then i tried a few commands to reach the save but any worked.. :/ I am not allowed to use Firefox (corporate rules..)

Comment: You can raise new issue about automated handling download prompt in IE as my ticket was raised half year ago... Maybe someone will give you an answer. Good luck!

Comment: OK. I am now trying a different approach..  disable this dialog box from IE 11 downloading straight it to Downloads folder.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me and when I look at the source code of the page it looks like it should find that element, but for whatever reason it doesn't work for me no matter what I try. I even tried finding by id "Ribbon.List.Actions.ExportToSpreadsheet-Large" but I just don't have any luck. Anyone else come across this issue?